# Detect duplicate GA4 page views in google sheet via appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics-4

**Overview**

I am building an application where I want to check for duplicate ga4 page view codes for a client's websites via app script. Once the data is retrieved, I want to paste this data into my sheet. Pasting data into the sheet is already figured out.

**To capture network requests:**

```
ga4Id = [];

var capture_resource = performance.getEntriesByType('resource');
for (var i= 0; i<capture_resource.length; i++) {
var results = capture_resource[i].name;
if (results.includes('en=page_view')) {
var final = results.split('&')
ga4Id.push(final[1],);
    
}
    
    
}

console.log(ga4Id)

//Output Data
(2) ['tid=G-XXXXXX', 'tid=G-XXXXX']
```

If I use this script under Chrome Developer Tools >> Snippets, I can capture network requests and see the GA4 IDs deployed. How can I capture this information through the app script, where I can input the website URL and get a duplicate code status?

I also explored Cheerio Library but I wasn't sure how to Cheerio Library with network requests. Or if someone can suggest a third-party tool that can help me with the use case.

[image: Sample Input and Output]

Let's say I want to find out my client abc.com has a duplicate GA4 page view, so I will add the website URL in an input field for which I want the status. Once the results are backed, I want to log the results into a row such as `abc.com has two GA4 properties with the same ID - G-1234567890 & G-1234567890`. The HTML part and pasting the result back to the sheet are already figured out. I want to figure out how to get the results for ``abc.com```.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I can input the website URL and get a duplicate code status`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Let's say I want to find out my client ```abc.com``` has a duplicate GA4 page view, so I will add the website URL in an input field for which I want the status. Once the results are backed, I want to log the results into a row such as ``` abc.com has two GA4 properties with the same ID - G-1234567890 & G-1234567890```

Comment: @Tanaike I have updated the question with more details.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In order to test your situation, can you provide a sample URL and the sample output values you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike Here is one of the client website - https://covid19criticalcare.com/ I added the code under Chrome Developers Tools >> Scripts mentioned above, ```To capture network requests```. The expected output is ['tid=G-XXXXXXXXXX']

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply of `Thanks for your reply. ['tid=G-XXXXXXXXXX'] - This is the Google Analytics 4 Measurement ID, I want to retrieve, but when I run this script I get this format [ 'tId=drjFpZuKky' ]. Here is the highlighted value that I am trying to get - drive.google.com/file/d/1EJ1NfOaviU2BQKRbT9cFzo3Nj-y8SCcb/… `, I understood that my understanding of your question was not correct. In this case, I have to delete my answer. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: No worries about understanding. Can you propose another answer, if possible?

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I could correctly understand your question, I would like to think of a solution. When I found a solution, I would like to post it.